# How run AppImage with AppArmor

Tags: linux, archlinux, apparmor, appimage

I have Archlinux with AppArmor and I get this error trying to run this AppImage (standard-notes-3.150.38-linux-x86_64.AppImage):

```
$ Downloads/standard-notes-3.150.38-linux-x86_64.AppImage 
fuse: mount failed: Permission denied

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
$
```

I don't have issues running other AppImage with AppArmor (pcloud).

To try to solve issue I started auditd service

```
$ sudo systemctl start auditd.service
```

And in another window I have running:

```
$ sudo aa-genprof /home/oscar/Downloads/standard-notes-3.150.38-linux-x86_64.AppImage 
Updating AppArmor profiles in /etc/apparmor.d.

Before you begin, you may wish to check if a
profile already exists for the application you
wish to confine. See the following wiki page for
more information:
https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/Profiles

Profiling: /home/user/Downloads/standard-notes-3.150.38-linux-x86_64.AppImage

Please start the application to be profiled in
another window and exercise its functionality now.

Once completed, select the "Scan" option below in 
order to scan the system logs for AppArmor events. 

For each AppArmor event, you will be given the 
opportunity to choose whether the access should be 
allowed or denied.

[(S)can system log for AppArmor events] / (F)inalizar
```

It get issues and ask for add a line in AppArmor profile to solve issue or other options.

But this way I couldn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/run-appimages.html there is a solution:

> For type 1 AppImages:
>
> $ mkdir mountpoint
>
> $ sudo mount my.AppImage mountpoint/
>
> # you can now inspect the contents
>
> $ sudo umount mountpoint/

> For type 2 AppImages:
>
> $ mkdir mountpoint
>
> $ my.AppImage --appimage-offset
>
> $ 123456
>
> $ sudo mount my.AppImage mountpoint/ -o offset=123456
>
> # you can now inspect the contents
>
> $ sudo umount mountpoint/
>
> Note that the number 123456 is just an example here, you will likely see another number.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Install libfuse package from aur.

```bash
paru -S lib32-fuse2
```

or

```bash
yay -S lib32-fuse2
```

Comment: I don't want to install lib32-fuse2 in my x86_64 PC.